# Side effects in import statements

Tags: typescript, module, decorator

Starting from the [Basic Example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-rest#basic-usage) in `typescript-rest`, I wanted to modularise by separating the `HelloService` class into its own file. Here it goes:

```ts
// hello-service.ts
import { Path, GET, PathParam } from "typescript-rest";

@Path("/hello")
export class HelloService {
  @Path(":name")
  @GET
  sayHello( @PathParam('name') name: string): string {
    return "Hello " + name;
  }
}
```

```ts
// index.ts
import * as express from "express";
import { Server } from "typescript-rest";

import './hello-service' // this works

// the following don't work
// import { HelloService } from './hello-service';
// import * as Foo from './hello-service'

// however they do work, but iif:
// new HelloService()
// new Foo.HelloService()

let app: express.Application = express();
Server.buildServices(app);

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Rest Server listening on port 3000!');
});
```

In short, I was expecting the 3 import statements:

```
import './hello-service'
import { HelloService } from './hello-service';
import * as Foo from './hello-service'
```

to be equivalent in terms of side-effects. My original interpretation was that the file gets loaded and interpreted and so the `@decorators` do their magic (I don't know how they work under the hood) but apparently not.

## Can someone point out the difference between these statements and explain the different outcomes?

---

Here is the doc on [modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) and [module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

**edit**: I know it is also possible to [explicitly register services](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-rest#registering-services) with this library but that's not what I'm interested in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation comes from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-module-for-side-effects-only

This is part of optimisations done at transpiler level, that checks if no exports from a given import is used, it gets sacked out from the final bundle