# Lit-element dependency not being recognized by TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webpack, lit

I have two `lit` elements, `RootElement`, and `CustomElement`. `RootElement` is imported directly into my `index.html` with `<script type="module">`, and it shows up fine. To import `CustomElement`, I put this in `RootElement`'s `render()` method:

```
  render() {
    return html`<script
        type="module"
        src="./path/to/customelement.ts"
      ></script>
      <custom-element></custom-element>`;
  }
```

But nothing shows up in the UI. If I put an import statement at the top of my code like so:

```
import { CustomElement } from "./path/to/customelement.ts";
```

Then it shows up as "unused", which makes sense since I haven't included it in the code.

However, if I *do* include `CustomElement` somewhere in my code (for example as a single statement, `CustomElement;`, at the bottom of the file), then it is no longer marked as "unused" and `<custom-element></custom-element>` renders properly as I would have expected.

What's going on here? What do I need in my `tsconfig.js` to convince the transpiler this dependency is necessary without me having to provide it in a useless statement somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the handbook under [Additional Import Syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html#additional-import-syntax) you need an import without variables:

> In this case, the `import` does nothing. However, all of the code in `maths.ts` was evaluated, which could trigger side-effects which affect other objects.

Custom elements are registered as side-effects, so all you need is to import the module. This would look like you have it:

```
import "./path/to/customelement.ts";
```

As in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907692/1426891), even an unused dependency is insufficient: transpilers can remove unused variables as a courtesy, but if you specify that there are no variables to consume, then the transpiler will keep the module you import and ensure it runs before the module that imports it.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to import the module but not as a default export:

```
import "./path/to/customelement.ts";
```